# Magento 2.1.2 Video's not showing with images while changing swatches

Tags: magento2

I'm using magento 2.1.2.I have an issue after implementing a solution that when clicking on the configurable product swatches images should change like color red is selected it should show the red images and so on.

By default in magento it was not working so i have implemented the solution listed here.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/e67e1dfb30a1a7c30133e6a347b3fc929a1bf4b6

After that images are now swatching when clicking on the color or size but video's are not showing before this solution it was showing configurable product images and videos but images change was not working.

Any thought about his

Answer (score 0):

This was a known bug in this version of magento - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6331

Updating to `2.2.x` should resolve this issue.